# Finding sublist of max length giving wrong results

Tags: python, list

I'm passing a list of lists `dataset` to a function. My goal is to get the length of the biggest list. However, I'm not able to get the correct results. I'm doing something like this:

```
def func(dataset):
   m = 0

   for line in dataset:
        if len(line) > m:
            m = len(line)

   print(m)
```

I'm getting really large numbers as the result. But if I just print `len(line)` above the `if` statement, then the correct values seem to be printed. Please help me understand what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: your code seems correct. Now show the input and what is your expected output. if you input is too large put a link or something.

Comment: Your function doesn't actually return anything - how are you calling it and how are you determining the result is wrong?

Comment: Resolved. I was getting the right answer which was an anomalously large value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `max(map(len,dataset))` but you should make sure all elements of your list are lists.  For example, if you have a string in there, `len` will give you the length of that string.

Comment: Resolved. I was getting the right answer which was an anomalously large value. Thanks for answering!